# How to tell Dozer to use LinkedHashSet collection in destination field?

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

In first class i have field:

```
private Set<Country> countries;

public Set<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public void setCountries(Set<Country> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
}
```

which will contain LinkedHashSet implementation.

In second class i have identical declaration, but during mapping, Dozer creates HashSet implementation in destination class, which destroys the order of elements. How to tell Dozer to use LinkedHashSet in destination class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Dozer maps a `Set`, it uses the [`org.dozer.util.CollectionUtils.createNewSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.dozer/dozer/5.2.2/org/dozer/util/CollectionUtils.java#CollectionUtils.createNewSet%28java.lang.Class%29) to create the destination `Set` instance. You get either a `HashSet` or `TreeSet`.

If the order of your elements is the same as their natural order you might use a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) in the destination. If not, then you need to create the destination object yourself and provide the desired `Set` implementation.

Dozer allows using custom [create methods](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customCreateMethod.html) or custom [bean factories](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custombeanfactories.html) to instantiate objects beyond using the default constructor so you could use either method:

**Create method**

Java code:

```
public class MyInstanceCreator {
    public static DestinationObject createDestinationObject() {
        DestinationObject result = new DestinationObject();
        result.setCountries(new LinkedHashSet<Country>());
        return result;
    }
    private MyInstanceCreator() { }
}
```

mapping:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a create-method="MyInstanceCreator.createDestinationObject">DestinationObject</class-a>
    <class-b>SourceObject</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>countries</a>
        <b>countries</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

**Bean factory**

Java code:

```
public class MyBeanFactory implements BeanFactory {
    public Object createBean(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass, String targetBeanId) {
        DestinationObject result = new DestinationObject();
        result.setCountries(new LinkedHashSet<Country>());
        return result;
    }
}
```

mapping:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a bean-factory="MyBeanFactory">DestinationObject</class-a>
    <class-b>SourceObject</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>countries</a>
        <b>countries</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```