# Dozer Mapping Set to Set

Tags: dozer

Hi I am trying to use Dozer to map my Hibernate domain object to a DTO.  The source mapping is an Object which contains a Set.  Using the API transform the mapping works fine but the ordering in my resultant Set is not preserved.  Is there a way to preserve the ordering in the result set? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Set doesn't support ordering by default.  Have you tried using LinkedHashSet as the implementation?

I recently did something similar using TreeSet.  I converted an unordered set to an ordered set.  The secret is to create an empty TreeSet in your DTO before the mapping.

```
TreeSet<MyClass> mySet = new TreeSet<MyClass>(new MyComparator());
myDTO.setMyClasses(mySet);
mapper.map(otherBean, myDTO);
```

After the Dozer mapping, the ordering in the target (myDTO) will match that of your comparator.

I suspect if you similarly pre-set the implementation of Set in your target DTO to LinkedHashSet, then the ordering of the original set would be maintained.  If not, try setting the implementation of your source bean to LinkedHashSet as well.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this question that explains how to tell Dozer to use a LinkedHashSet:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946350/how-to-tell-dozer-to-use-linkedhashset-collection-in-destination-field